# Local Storage not saving any of my form inputs

Tags: javascript, storage, local

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qu6R.png)

SO I have a form that when submits it goes to another html page.
Im trying to get the variables saved so i can then use them on the other webpage, however nothing saves to the local storage. I've tried everything i can think of, but nothing has changed.
The page is successfully getting the info when it changes page, but because it doesnt save to local storage, it has nothing to grab

Comment: Consider using cookies for this purpose: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a runnable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) See [How to create a Minimal reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
In general please post code, error messages, markup, etc. as text, not as a picture of text.